# setStreamMute with OnReceive in broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-audiomanager

I'm working on a simple app, which could mute `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` at specific time and unmute it after specific running time.

I use `AlarmManager` to trigger the action and do the `setStreamMute(STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true/false)` in the `onReceived` of `BroadcastReceiver`. The core code of Alarm set is below:

```
// mute task
Calendar muteCal = getTaskCalendar(i, curTask.getHour(), curTask.getMin(), 0);
PendingIntent mutePendingIntent = getBoardCastPendingIntent(ctxt, "tag", "Mute", muteRequestCodeBase);

// unmute task
Calendar unMuteCal = getTaskCalendar(i, curTask.getHour(), curTask.getMin(), curTask.getPeriod());
PendingIntent unmutePendingIntent = getBoardCastPendingIntent(ctxt, "tag", "UnMute", unmuteRequestCodeBase);

alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, muteCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, mutePendingIntent);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, unMuteCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, unmutePendingIntent);
```

Following is the mute code and what's done at onReceive function

```
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
     MuterHelper.setToMute(ctxt);
}
public class MuterHelper {
    public static void setToMute(Context context) {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
    }
```

When the mute time is arrived, noReceive setToMute, and there will not be sound notification when the new sms is arrived, everything works very well.

However, after a specific time, the `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` will auto unmute, according to the API Documents(The mute command is protected against client process death: if a process with an active mute request on a stream dies, this stream will be unmuted automatically), And I checked the system log, there is a log said

```
"00:53:33.250 W/AudioService(  312): Volume service client died for stream: 5"
```

OK, here is my question. I want to know how to keep the service client alive and keep the `NOTIFICATION` unmute until another unmute task `setStreamMute(false)`.

Thanks for all your helping!